# SuSE always logs a user in TVM session

Tags: linux, gnome, suse

I recently installed Suse Linux enterprise Desktop 11 on my box. I created an user and logged in first time into a GNOME session without any problems. Last time I logged in I selected the session as TWM and that got me into the T windows manager just fine. Now when I log out and try to log back into a GNOME session, it will still log me into the TVM session. I have tried restarting the box but that has not helped.

However, when I remote log in to the machine it will let me get on the GNOME session just fine.

I'm guessing this is probably a really simple fix, however I am a Linux newbie and doing a google search isn't yielding me what I'm looking for.

Thanks in advance for your help,

Rohan

Answer (score 0):

I came across this in a CentOS instance. What I did was `yum erase twm` and the wm has no choice but to load gnome after re-login. If you don't need TWM, and can't get it done using other methods, just do a

`zypper remove twm`

or use whatever name TWM has on SUSE.